# Windows Server 2008 - Disable Plesk

Tags: windows-server-2008

I just leased a new Dedicated Server running Windows Server 2008.

How do I disable Plesk for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/Plesk8.2/Windows/Docs/plesk-8.2-win-installation-guide/32243.htm) seems to make it sound fairly easy.

> To uninstall Plesk for Windows:

1. Log in to your system as Administrator or another user with Administrator privileges.
2. Go to Start > Control Panel > Add or Remove Programs.
3. Select Plesk for Microsoft Windows and click Remove.
4. You will be asked whether you really want to uninstall Plesk 8.1 for Windows. Confirm the removal by clicking Yes. After Plesk is removed from your server, the restart confirmation will appear. Confirm the restart to finish the uninstallation process.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just tell the hosting company that you want a server that doesn't have Plesk on it?  That should also translate into a discount, since you/they aren't paying for a plesk licence.

Comment: I think that is generally good advice, but not an option at my host (1&1).

Comment: @GeorgeWBush This is the best way to go about it. Though, 1&1 are generally rubbish anyway; you can do much better elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed. Also please note that this question is 6 years old. AWS is clearly a better option.